# filter the areaName by specific id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arraylist

I have called an API and bind the data on UI but also I have passed the id  `allArea._id` as the parameter on `addCoupon` Function by onClick Method. By this function `addCoupon()` I got the id but I just want to filter the areaName by this specific id

```
addCoupon (id) {
        console.log('id',id)
    }


{this.state.allArea.map((allArea, i) => (
 <TableRow key={i}>
  <TableCell >{allArea.areaName}</TableCell>
  <TableCell >{allArea.cityName}</TableCell>
  <TableCell ><IconButton aria-label="edit" 
    onClick={this.addCoupon.bind(this,allArea._id)} >
    <EditIcon />
    </IconButton><IconButton aria-label="delete">
    <DeleteIcon />
    </IconButton></TableCell>
 </TableRow>
   ))}

//Data Schema


0:{
created: "2020-02-10T07:18:10.152Z"
_id: "5e37cc3727f3a8228ca33442"
areaName: "aaaaa"
cityName: "Jodhpur"
cityId: "5e37cbbc27f3a8228ca33441"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to do this Choose what suits you best:

```
//Filter the array data
addCoupon (id) {
    return this.state.allArea.filter(area => return area._id === id })
}

// Or try to pass the all object not just (allArea._id) then get areaName.
<IconButton aria-label="edit" onClick={this.addCoupon.bind(this,area)}  >

addCoupon (area) {
    return area.areaName
}
```

By the way is better to change your parameter name by (area not allArea) to avoid repetition

```
{this.state.allArea.map((area, i) => ())}
```